# Embed script into docker container to run after main process starts

Tags: docker, background-process, process-management, alpine-linux, docker-compose

For a particular docker image (based on alpine) I want to run some custom code *after* the container starts. I want that code inside the container, so it's easy to use and everything is self-contained. Ordinarily I'd override the container's entrypoint or command, but that's not possible for this case.

My solution:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
volumes:
  - ./entrypoint-custom.sh:/entrypoint-custom.sh:ro
entrypoint: /entrypoint-custom.sh      # override Dockerfile default of '/someapp'
```

`entrypoint-custom.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# custom pre-start code
# ...

# custom post-start code
(sleep 10; echo I run after start) & \
  exec /someapp "$@"                     # '/someapp' is container's actual executable, from image's original ENTRYPOINT
```

That works. And using `exec` means signals (e.g. for log rotation) are correctly sent to the `/someapp` executable. If I check the container's logs (`docker logs someapp`) then it shows the app starts as usual, and some time later my delayed task prints to the output.

In theory I could replace that `echo` with whatever post-start logic I'd like.

Concerns:

- If I exec into the container and run `ps`, it still shows `12 root 0:00 [entrypoint-cust]` - I'm unsure of the ramifications?
- Could there be any unintended consequences for this approach?